# Domino10 appDevPack: "Error: Cannot find module '@domino/domino-db'"

Tags: node.js, node-modules, lotus-domino, node-red, domino-appdev-pack

Just installed the latest Domino 10.0.1 Server on my linux machine and also installed and configured the latest proton package. As far as I can tell it's all running fine.

Next I plan to try my first Node-RED flow using the new Domino10 nodes. So I installed the 'node-red-contrib-dominodb' palette.

Finally tried my first very simple flow trying to query node-demo.nsf as it's described [here](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/collaboration-solutions/2018/12/14/how-to-access-domino-v10-using-node-red/). From what I read there I assumed that it's sufficient to install the palette, but that obviously is not the case:

as soon as I hit 'Deploy' I receive this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@domino/domino-db'
```

So I thought that I maybe still have to do a global install in node.js using

```
npm install -g <package-path>/domino-domino-db-1.1.0.tgz
```

This indeed created a local @domino/domino-db module inside my node.js npm\node_modules folder. But obviously my node-red environment doesn't know about it.

Question is: how do I register / install that npm package for my local node-red environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM's instructions (https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-dominodb#Installation)
Say to go view this guide(https://github.com/stefanopog/node-red-contrib-dominodb/blob/master/docs/Using%20the%20new%20Domino%20V10%20NodeRED%20nodes%202.pdf) for installing the domino-db module.

The link is broken, here's an old copy: https://github.com/stefanopog/node-red-contrib-dominodb/blob/a723ef88498c5bfa243abd956a7cc697f0a42610/docs/Using%20the%20new%20Domino%20V10%20NodeRED%20nodes%202.pdf

I believe the section you want is called "Import the tarball".  The steps before that require you to unpack and then re-pack the module... which is unnecessary.  Just use the tgz that was in the AppDev Pack to begin with.

Comment: I'll note, that I'm not familiar with Node-RED.  We hope to have our module on NPM soon... but the instructions for how to use our module in the meantime should be updated to be more clear.  I was certainly confused reading them.

Comment: Thanks for hinting that instruction; unfortunately this considers 1) a Linux installation and 2) a cloud installation. - Currently being in the process of learning the ins and outs of Node-RED I'm testing this on my local Windows machine. Is it right to assume that I need to add my @domino/domino-db folder to my local Windows PATH?

Comment: ok, think I got it: created a new NODE_PATH env var and added the path to my \npm\node_modules. Now this path is listed under 'module.paths', and my node-red flow at least starts without that error message